on the definition of prime ideals

An ideal $P$ of $R$ is said to be a prime ideal if and only if $P≠R$, and whenever $A$ and $B$ are ideals of $R$, then $AB⊆P$ implies $A⊆P$ or $B⊆P$.

but what if $A⊆P$ and $B⊆P$? is it still a prime ideal?

it's an inclusive or. in general all ors should be inclusive unless made clear otherwise (e.g. "exactly one of the following is true:" or etc.)
